# iOS Photos App - Shard Album URL Scheme

Tags: photos

What’s the URL scheme for an iCloud shared album? I know it uses photos://, but I don’t know what the full URL is. The ID of the shared album is B0N59UlCqEPDuj. I've tried photos://sharedalbum/B0N59UlCqEPDuj and photos://album/B0N59UlCqEPDuj. I don't want to use the iCloud.com URL as I'm wanting to share it with people privately, but I want to give them a link they can use.

Comment: I think the photos:// URL will only open an album on a local computer; it will not let you share something remotely. Is that what you want?

Comment: I've added the user to the shared album already. They have access. Now I just need to generate a link that they can use to view that album with just one tap. I don't want to use the iCloud.com link as that means anyone who has that link can view the album.